Procedure FINTAG_INSTEADOFINSERTTRIGGER, Line 41 Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column
I encountered the following error while attempting to restore the 10.0.40 UAT.bacpac on a development environment running version 10.0.38:

Procedure FINTAG_INSTEADOFINSERTTRIGGER, Line 41 Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a resolution from Microsoft Support?
Error SQL72014: Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 273, Level 16, State 1, Procedure FINTAG_INSTEADOFINSERTTRIGGER, Line 41 Cannot insert an 
explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[FINTAG_INSTEADOFINSERTTRIGGER]
    ON [dbo].FinTag
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS BEGIN
           DECLARE @ErrorLevel AS INT = 0;
           DECLARE @Delimiter AS CHAR;
           DECLARE @IsDelimiterInValues AS BIT;
           DECLARE @ErrorDelimiter AS CHAR = '!';
           SELECT @Delimiter = CASE (SELECT DELIMITER
                                     FROM   FINTAGPARAMETERS
                                     WHERE  PARTITION = (SELECT PARTITION
                                                         FROM   INSERTED)) WHEN 1 THEN '|' WHEN 2 THEN '.' WHEN 3 THEN '_' WHEN 4 THEN '-' WHEN 5 THEN 
'~' ELSE @ErrorDelimiter END;
           SELECT @IsDelimiterInValues = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, concat(TAG01, TAG02, TAG03, TAG04, TAG05, TAG06, TAG07, TAG08, TAG09, TAG10, 
TAG11, TAG12, TAG13, TAG14, TAG15, TAG16, TAG17, TAG18, TAG19, TAG20)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           FROM   inserted;
           DECLARE @Hash AS NVARCHAR (64);
           DECLARE @DisplayValue AS N
Time elapsed 1:14:17.66

This error occurred approximately one hour after starting the script.
C:\sqlpackage-win-x64-en-162.3.566.1> ./SqlPackage.exe /a:import /sf:C:\Backup\dbbackup.bacpac /tsn:localhost /tdn:AxDB2 /ttsc:true /p:CommandTimeout=1200 
I have searched online for solutions, but none have worked. I also updated the local environment to the latest version without success.

Same issue
Error in restoring 10.0.39 UAT bacpac file on Development Env

Aside... the trigger code is flawed: it assumes that there will only ever be one row in the inserted virtual table. Triggers on SQL Server act on row sets, so the inserted and deleted virtual tables can contain zero, one or many rows.

@AlwaysLearning it's probably some internal microsoft dynamics trigger so hopefully they know what they're doing

Aside - that's not the whole trigger definition. Notice how it ends with DECLARE @DisplayValue AS N and there's no INSERT statement to be found?

I have solved this issue by following these steps:

Download the latest binary from LCS and update it on the local VM.
Follow the steps from this link. this link


Go to Feature Management and turn on the Financial Tags feature.
Go to the Data maintenance portal and click /Check for updates/.
Run the /Deploy financial tag table triggers/ data maintenance job

When the job finishes successfully, you can take a new export database and then try to load that one into the development environment.
